# Unable to add pictures to new folder

Tags: android

I have a trouble adding pictures to a new folder. For some reason when my phone is connected to the computer and is used as an emulator the pictures do infact get saved to the correct folder. But once I disconnect the phone from the computer it does not save the pictures to the folder. I have included the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
```

My code is bellow

```
public class Camera extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
Intent i;
ImageView iv;
ImageButton ib;
Button b;
final static int cameraData = 0;
Bitmap bmp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);
    initialize();
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
}

private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    iv =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivReturnPic);
    ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibTakePic);
    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bSetWall);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    ib.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.bSetWall:
        try {
            getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(bmp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    case R.id.ibTakePic:
        int imageNum = 0;
        Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "BeautifulPlaces");
        imagesFolder.mkdirs(); // <----
        String fileName = "image_" + String.valueOf(imageNum) + ".jpg";
        File output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
        while (output.exists()){
            imageNum++;
            fileName = "image_" + String.valueOf(imageNum) + ".jpg";
            output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
        }
        Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(output);
        imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
        startActivityForResult(imageIntent, 0);

    }
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the external storage before writing data to it. Because it may be unavailable.

You can refer to this document: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

```
String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (extStorageState.equalsIgnoreCase(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))  {
    //  For ensure there is no problem, I usually do one more checking here
    File externalDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if (externalDir.canWrite())  {
        //  Do you job here
        //  ...            

    }
}
```

Comment: I added checks to ensure the external storage is available as suggested again the program works when the phone is connected to the computer but not when its disconnected.

Comment: Is there a permission i am missing??? because its weird that it works while connected to the computer or is it because the app isnt signed but it still runs so that should be it.

Comment: I think you should do your saving process in onActivityResult. Because image data is not pass back until the camera activity has finished.